# tspan elements appear outside of SVG text bounds in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, vector-graphics

I'm making a website for a local band and they wanted a design with outlined text. I look up how to do this and found that the only way to have transparent fill and a solid outline is to use SVG text. I've built the site for them and it works fine in Chrome/Firefox/Opera, but there are a number of problems in Safari.

When you hover over one of the letters of the logo on the first page, it should change to solid white and play a sound. To do this, I've split the text element by letters, using tspan elements, and have each letter trigger a JavaScript hover event. For some reason the hover area in Safari is below the letters themselves, is there any way I can force them back to their correct position?

[image: Hovering over a letter]

Here's the HTML for the SVG text. There are two copies of the text layered over the top of each other, this is because I needed to fade in a glow effect and this was the only way I could find to do it (incidentally, the glow effect doesn't render in Safari, but that's a separate issue). For this example, however, the styling is directly applied to the tspan element (with no fade) and the `#glowLogo` element remains hidden.

```html
    <div id="logoWrap">
      <svg id="mainLogo" viewbox="0 0 10 2">
        <text id="glowLogo" class="shadow" x="5" y="1" text-anchor="middle" font-size="0.9" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="Arial Black">
          <tspan data-sound="M">M</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="O">O</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="O2">O</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="N">N</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="O3">O</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="V">V</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="E">E</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="R">R</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="S">S</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="U">U</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="N">N</tspan>
        </text>
        <text id="soundLogo" class="textHover" x="5" y="1" text-anchor="middle" font-size="0.9" fill="none" stroke-width=".015" stroke="#FFFFFF" font-family="Arial Black">
          <tspan data-sound="M">M</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="O">O</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="O2">O</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="N">N</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="O3">O</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="V">V</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="E">E</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="R">R</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="S">S</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="U">U</tspan>
          <tspan data-sound="N2">N</tspan>
        </text>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```css
    #logoWrap {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

    #linksPage {
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 100vh;
    }

    #mainLogo {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      cursor: default;
      margin-top: -6vw;
    }

    .shadow,
    tspan.on {  /*  class applied by javascript event */
      fill: #FFFFFF;
      text-shadow: 0 0 15px #FFFFFF;
    }

    tspan.on {  /*  class applied by javascript event */
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    text a {
      cursor: pointer;
      cursor: hand;
    }

    #glowLogo {
      opacity: 0;
    }
```

Here's the JavaScript event, for clarification:

```js
    $(".textHover tspan").hover(function() {
      $(this).addClass("on");
      document.getElementById($(this).attr("data-sound")).currentTime = 0;
      document.getElementById($(this).attr("data-sound")).play();
    }, function() {
      $(this).removeClass("on");
    });
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Your font size is below 1; probably Safari produces a rounding error. Try multiplying all relevant size values with 10. (viewBox, x, y, stroke-width, font-size and text-shadow in the stylesheet)

Comment: @ccprog Works perfectly thank you! Not only solved the two problems I posted on here, but another few bugs I was having with the text on the page.